# Constraint Layout - Move view below of the neighbour view if neighbour has reached a certain width

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 views.

The **view A** is in wrap_content and with a max_width of 100dp. Then there's this **view B** next to him. **I want view B** to move below **view A** when **view A** reachs 100 dp width.

How can I accomplish this with Constraint Layout and xml? Or must be done programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can move change a view's constraint's programmatically. You could listen for the view's width and perform a change when it reaches >100dp.

Video on the subject:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sPOtGqd5OA